Merge strategy to merge base product functionality to product customer specific branch
I've developed a product. I have a base version of it, but then there are customer specific developments that I managed in specific branches that derive from the main base product branch.
What is the best strategy to merge a new base functinality to the customer branches? The ideal is also automate it as well.

You can set the required branch policies for main branch. The changes to main branch can be made only through pull requests.
When you develop the new functionality, you can create a feature branch based on the main branch. Once the feature is ready and tested, create a Pull request and merge it back to the main branch. This is to make sure the main branch always good and ready.
Then, you can create a pipeline, which will have a main branch trigger. In the pipeline, you can run the git commands to auto merge the main branch to the customer branches. The pipeline will be triggered when you merge a feature branch to the main branch.
Assuming you have the following branches: customer-A, customer-B and main. My Sample Yaml file:
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- checkout: self
  persistCredentials: true

- script: |
    git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
    git config --global user.name "Your Name"
    for branch in customer-A customer-B; do
        git checkout $branch
        git merge origin/main
        git push origin $branch
    done
  displayName: 'Merge main into customer branches'

Test result: The update in main branch is pushed to the customer branches.

Note:
You should give your build service account the Git 'Contribute' permission of the repo. Otherwise, you may see errors like TF401027: You need the Git 'GenericContribute' permission to perform this action. Details: identity 'Build\xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx', scope 'repository'.

The above is an idealized example. In a real-world scenario, you might need to deal with merge conflicts, and you might need different pipelines or stages to build, test, and deploy your code. The specific process needs to be adjusted according to your needs.
